# Сформировать таблицу при помощи PHP на основе данных из MySQL

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть массив такого типа:

```
array(4) {     
 array(4) {["name"]=> "name_one" , ["y"]=> "2016", ["q"]=> "2", ["st"]=>  "1"}     
 array(4) {["name"]=> "name_one" , ["y"]=> "2017", ["q"]=> "3", ["st"]=>  "2"}     
 array(4) {["name"]=> "name_two" , ["y"]=> "2017", ["q"]=> "1", ["st"]=>  "1"}     
 array(4) {["name"]=> "name_two" , ["y"]=> "2017", ["q"]=> "2", ["st"]=>  "2"} 
}
```

Необходимо сформировать и заполнить таблицу на основе данных из этого массива.

[image: таблица]

С выводом заголовкой и формированием самой таблицы справилась, а вот как заполнить ячейки, не могу придумать.

Comment: Яна, ты бы отформатировал массив, там есть кнопочка `код`

Comment: Перестрой структуру на `[name_one => [2016 => [q1 => null, q2 => 1, ..], ..], ..]` перед рендером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала перегруппируем данные с учётом зависимостей.
Вместе с тем, сохраним множества `names`/`years`/`qs` для построения шапки.

```
$rows = [
  ['name' => 'name_one', 'y' => '2016', 'q' => '2', 'st' => 1],
  ['name' => 'name_one', 'y' => '2017', 'q' => '3', 'st' => 2],
  ['name' => 'name_two', 'y' => '2017', 'q' => '1', 'st' => 1],
  ['name' => 'name_two', 'y' => '2017', 'q' => '2', 'st' => 2],
];

$data = [];

$names = [];
$years = [];
$qs = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $link = &$data;
  foreach (['name', 'y'] as $field) {
      if (!isset($link[$row[$field]])) $link[$row[$field]] = [];
      $link = &$link[$row[$field]];
  }
  $link[$row['q']] = $row['st'];
  unset($link);
  //
  $names[$row['name']] = true;
  $years[$row['y']] = true;
  $qs[$row['q']] = true;
}
// Опционально сортируем
$names = array_keys($names); sort($names);
$years = array_keys($years); sort($years);
$qs = array_keys($qs); sort($qs);
```

Структура есть, дело за малым - отрендерить таблицу:
В шапке 2 строки, в первой годы с соответствующим `colspan`.
Далее выводим сами данные.
Для перебора ключей может использоваться `foreach($years as $y => $_)`, однако мы уже извлекли ключи с помощью `array_keys`.

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/gGKeH)

```
?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
      <th>Name
      <?foreach($years as $y):?>
        <th colspan="<?=count($qs)?>"><?=$y?>
      <?endforeach?>
  <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;
      <?foreach($years as $y):?>
        <?foreach($qs as $q):?>
          <th>q<?=$q?>
        <?endforeach?>
      <?endforeach?>

  <?foreach($names as $name):?>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$name?>
    <?foreach($years as $y):?>
      <?foreach($qs as $q):?>
        <td><?=isset($data[$name][$y][$q]) ? $data[$name][$y][$q] : '' ?>
      <?endforeach?>
    <?endforeach?>
  <?endforeach?>
</table>
```

Результат будет выглядеть как-то так:

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Name
    <th colspan="3">2016              
    <th colspan="3">2017       
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;
    <th>q1                  
    <th>q2                  
    <th>q3                                
    <th>q1                  
    <th>q2                  
    <th>q3                    
  <tr>
    <td>name_one                  
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
  <tr>
    <td>name_two                  
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [функцию printf()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php). Например в цикле можно перебирать массив или данные из БД и выводить нужное вот так в виде строк таблицы

```
printf("
    <tr class='%s'>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
    </tr>
    ", $a, $b, $c, $d
);
```

Вместо заполнителя `%s` будут вставляться значения из переменных. Порядок имеет значение.

Для удобства можно собрать иной массив из того, что у вас есть.

Comment: Опять ты свой `print_f` тулишь. Прекрати, это же неприлично.

Comment: @vp_arth А ты всё бузишь)) Ответил бы на вопрос тогда

Comment: Мне лень, я в комментах идею дал)

Comment: @vp_arth ну да, группировка упростит вывод. Но вот как человек выводит - вообще ни слова. Точнее судя по всему человек вывел пустую таблицу, а данными не заполнил.