# Преобразовать массив в дерево

Tags: php

Добрый день. Получаю при помощи mysqli_fetch_assoc массив такого формата

```
array(4) {     
array(5) {["cat"]=> "guest" , ["name"]=> "name_one" , ["y"]=> "2016", ["q"]=> "2", ["st"]=>  "1"}     
array(5) {["cat"]=> "guest" , ["name"]=> "name_one" , ["y"]=> "2017", ["q"]=> "3", ["st"]=>  "2"}     
array(5) {["cat"]=> "guest" , ["name"]=> "name_two" , ["y"]=> "2017", ["q"]=> "1", ["st"]=>  "1"}     
array(5) {["cat"]=> "guest" , ["name"]=> "name_two" , ["y"]=> "2017", ["q"]=> "2", ["st"]=>  "2"} 
}
```

Как на PHP преобразовать его в такое дерево

```
  {["cat"]=> "guest"{
        ["name"]=> "name_one"{
            ["y"]=> "2016"{
                ["q"]=> "2", 
                ["st"]=>"1"
            }
            ["y"]=> "2017"{
                ["q"]=> "3", 
                ["st"]=>"2"
            }
        }
        ["name"]=> "name_two"{
            ["y"]=> "2016"{
                ["q"]=> "2", 
                ["st"]=>"1"
            }
            ["y"]=> "2017"{
                ["q"]=> "3", 
                ["st"]=>"2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известен контекст вашей задачи, вам лучше не сохранять ключи в структуре(`name`, `y`...):

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/Ml6Yg)

```
$rows = [
  ['cat' => 'guest', 'name' => 'name_one', 'y' => '2016', 'q' => '2', 'st' => 1],
  ['cat' => 'guest', 'name' => 'name_one', 'y' => '2017', 'q' => '3', 'st' => 2],
  ['cat' => 'guest', 'name' => 'name_two', 'y' => '2017', 'q' => '1', 'st' => 1],
  ['cat' => 'guest', 'name' => 'name_two', 'y' => '2017', 'q' => '2', 'st' => 2],
];

$data = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $link = &$data;
  foreach (['cat', 'name', 'y'] as $field) {
      if (!isset($link[$row[$field]])) $link[$row[$field]] = [];
      $link = &$link[$row[$field]];
  }
  $link[$row['q']] = $row['st'];
  unset($link);
}
print_r($data);
```

[Полный ответ к связанному вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627114/176064)

---

Если же вам необходимо сохранить ключи, придётся ввести лишний уровень для отделения значений текущего уровня от списка потомков:

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/dUBK4)

```
$data = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $link = &$data;
  foreach (['cat', 'name', 'y'] as $field) {
      if (!isset($link[$field])) $link[$field] = [];
      if (!isset($link[$field][$row[$field]])) $link[$field][$row[$field]] = [];
      $link = &$link[$field][$row[$field]];
  }
  $link[] = ['q' => $row['q'], 'st' => $row['st']];
  unset($link);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Результат:

```
{
  "cat":{
    "guest":{
      "name":{
        "name_one":{
          "y":{
            "2016":[{"q":"2","st":1}],
            "2017":[{"q":"3","st":2}]
          }
        },
        "name_two":{
          "y":{
            "2017":[{"q":"1","st":1},{"q":"2","st":2}]}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Массив надо получать не с помощью mysqli, а с помощью PDO.

Тогда ничего перестраивать не придется, PDO все сделает за нас.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT name, y, q, st FROM table");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_GROUP);
```

[вернет нам массив уже сгруппированный по name](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP).

Comment: `FETCH_GROUP` вернёт дерево? Цитата: `Как преобразовать его в такое дерево`

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то можно попробовать такой способ, который отделяет ключи:

```
<?php
$assoc = array(
    array(
        "cat"  => "guest1",
        "name" => "name_one1",
        "y"    => "2000",
        "q"    => "my1",
        "st"   => 1
    ), 
    array(
        "cat"  => "guest2",
        "name" => "name_one2",
        "y"    => "2001",
        "q"    => "my2",
        "st"   => 2
    ), 
);

$three = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($assoc); $i++) { 
    foreach ($assoc[$i] as $key => $value) {
        $three[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($three);
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но в этом случае получается перестроенный "массив массивов" такого формата {guest, guest, guest, guest}  {name_one, name_one, name_two, name_two} {2016, 2017, 2017, 2017}  {2, 3, 1, 2}